# can not use selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/cagri/Desktop/chromedriver")
    val driver = ChromeDriver()
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
}
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/cagri/Desktop/chromedriver

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about your driver's directory. Please edit it with correct one. Or install it via brew it will saved under resources directory and it will not change while you update it via brew.

for example :

If your operating system is windows, try following code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/cagri/Desktop/chromedriver")
```